# How to exit the golang read-loop mode?

Tags: go, udp

I am using golang language. Now I have a UDP socket. I start a goroutine to receive the information returned by the server. The code running in goroutine is as follows:

```golang
func (udp_client *UDPClient) recvFrom() {
    var conns = *udp_client.conn
    var err error

    for {
        readBuff := make([]byte, recvBufferSize)
        _, err = conns.Read(readBuff)
        if err != nil {
            // boomer.RecordFailure("UDP", "RECV", 0.0, err.Error())
            log.Error("socket recv error.", zap.String("errMsg", err.Error()))
            return
        }

        udp_client.recvMessage <- readBuff
    }
}
```

How can I close this goroutine.

I tried to close the socket externally and let the program in goroutine exit, but it didn't seem to work. The program in goroutine seems to be stuck.

Thank you for reading. English is not my mother tongue. Please forgive my grammatical mistakes.

Looking forward to your reply, thank you!

Comment: When the socket is closed, it should detect it as an error and return from the goroutine. If this is not happening, maybe you are not reading from the channel, and it is blocked waiting there? Find out where the goroutine is waiting when you close the socket.

Comment: Goroutine is stuck in `_, err = conns.Read(readBuff)`, because there is no record related to `socket recv error` in my log

Comment: you can set a deadline, then, upon reading, check the error, unless it is a network timeout, exit the loop. This give you a chance to tick once in a while, thus, you can now select over a context to get input signal and exit.

Comment: If there are no logs, goroutine may be blocked in channel write, or connection read. Put logging statement before/after the connection read and channel write.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are looking for but ending of the loop is solely dependent on you. Your loop can keep on reading data until it sees some flag (Timer or message of close) to shut it-self down. If you are asking as how to how close it, then use conn.Close().

It will be better to put in a defered sentence, like: defer conn.Close().

Comment: Yes, I called `conn.Close()` outside goroutine and wrote the code to exit goroutine in err after `_, err = conns.Read(readBuff)` in goroutine, but goroutine didn't exit because I didn't find the record related to `socket recv error.` in the log

Comment: Rather than error log could you try to end the routine by receiving an exit message or Timer on your socket. That way we can eliminate the possibility of your channel being blocked. (My current thought is that you are ending the connection by a system interrupt)

Answer (score -1):

By reading the comment of function 'Close()', can saw this:

```
// Close closes the connection.
// Any blocked Read or Write operations will be unblocked and return errors.
    Close() error
```

So, I guess the problem maybe in somewhere else.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).